# How can I solve not selecting total listview when I scroll list page?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `listview` in my application. I have 5 columns in my `listview` and items are displayed dynamically. The problem is when I scroll my list the total list selected and the background of the `listpage` will be changed as black color.

Here my code is:

```
<TableLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"
     android:background="@drawable/bg">




     <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent">    


          <TextView 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/t1" 
              android:text="Tname"               
                 android:typeface="serif"
                  android:padding="3dip" 
             android:textColor="#9400D3">             

                       </TextView>
<TextView  
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/t2" 
              android:text="From"                            
                   android:textColor="#9400D3"               
                  android:typeface="serif"   
                           >
              </TextView>
<TextView 

              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/t3" 
              android:text="Arrival"            
                android:textColor="#9400D3"
                  android:typeface="serif"
             >
              </TextView>
<TextView 

              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/t4" 
              android:text="To" 
                android:textColor="#9400D3"             
            android:typeface="serif">
              </TextView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/t5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="Departure"
     android:textColor="#9400D3"  
            android:typeface="serif"  

     >
</TextView>
  </TableRow> 


    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"

        android:paddingLeft="0px" 
        android:focusable="false">

        </ListView>

</TableLayout>
```

my items listpage

```
<TableLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"  >  
     <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

       >    


<TextView 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/train" 
              android:text="train" 

              android:textColor="#FF0000" 
                 android:typeface="serif"
                  android:padding="3dip"               
              >
              </TextView>
<TextView  
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/from" 
              android:text="From" 

              android:textColor="#292421"
                 android:typeface="serif"

              >
              </TextView>
<TextView 

              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/arr" 
              android:text="arr"             

                android:textColor="#000080"
                   android:typeface="serif"

             >
              </TextView>
 <TextView          
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/to" 
              android:text="to"              
                 android:textColor="#292421"
                 android:typeface="serif"

              >
              </TextView> 
<TextView 

              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/dep" 
              android:text="Location" 

              android:textColor="#000080"
                 android:typeface="serif"
              ></TextView>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Please, tell me where I have done wrong..

Comment: Just set android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" on your listview (xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in Listview property